# Turn on GPS remotely for lost phone

Tags: gps, lost-phone

I misplaced my phone last night, I can still call it and see notifications on it through join. But my location services are turned off so I have no idea where it is. I tried android device manager but that is no good and tried find device on the xiaomi website. I do have root access on the phone so is there anyway I can enable gps remotely or do something to figure out where it is?

Comment: Our [lost-phone tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info) has a few solutions for you. Once you've tried one of them successfully, be welcome to  [answer your own question](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question), describing step-by-step how you succeeded :)

Comment: I had lost phone some time ago and had GPS turned off like you. Bad news I didn't find a way to remotely activate GPS, even some people told me that is impossible.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје same advice to you: the tag-wiki mentions two alternatives, one of them still being available.

Comment: there is a way using metasploit and meterpreter with a rooted phone but this is probably illegal where u live. therefore there is no viable way to do so